# Aggregate rows with string values in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataframe `df` with only `string` values. I need to aggregate these rows on `id`and `session` and fill the `NA` values. My original dataframe has 50 columns but this is just an example dataframe. You can assume that for each combination of `id` and `session` the values (string1 or string2) are the same, if they don't have an NA value.

```
session <- c('s1', 's1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's2')
string1 <- c('first_string1', NA, 'first_string1', NA, 'first_string3', NA)
string2 <- c(NA, 'second_string2', 'second_string2', 'second_string4', NA, NA)
df <- data.frame(id, session, string1, string2)

df

  id session       string1        string2
1  a      s1 first_string1           <NA>
2  a      s1          <NA> second_string2
3  a      s1 first_string1 second_string2
4  b      s2          <NA> second_string4
5  b      s2 first_string3           <NA>
6  b      s2          <NA>           <NA>
```

The final dataframe should look like this:

```
  id session       string1        string2
1  a      s1 first_string1 second_string2
2  b      s2 first_string3 second_string4
```

I have tried to using the aggregate function but I can't figure out how to get this working

Comment: What is the logic by which `first_string3` is associated with `second_string4`, given that neither are actually adjacent to each other anywhere in the starting data frame?

Comment: Thay both have the same `id` and `session`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `aggregate` you can do something like this, where you include a function that removes NAs and finds unique rows while aggregating:

```r
aggregate(df[c("string1", "string2")],
          by = list(id = id, session = session),
          function(x) unique(na.omit(x)))

#### OUTPUT ####

  id session       string1        string2
1  a      s1 first_string1 second_string2
2  b      s2 first_string3 second_string4
```

Base R's `merge` is another, perhaps slightly easier to understand, option:

```r
unique(na.omit(merge(df[c("id", "session", "string1")],
                     df[c("id", "session", "string2")],
                     by = c("id", "session")
                     )))

#### OUTPUT #### 

  id session       string1        string2
1  a      s1 first_string1 second_string2
2  b      s2 first_string3 second_string4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id, session) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("string")), ~unique(na.omit(.)))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
  id    session string1       string2       
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>         <chr>         
1 a     s1      first_string1 second_string2
2 b     s2      first_string3 second_string4
```

A base R solution

```
aggregate(cbind(string1, string2) ~ id + session, data = df, function(x) unique(na.omit(x)), na.action = na.pass)

  id session       string1        string2
1  a      s1 first_string1 second_string2
2  b      s2 first_string3 second_string4
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit clunky, but works:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by (id, session) %>%
  summarise(string1 =  paste(unique(string1[!is.na(string1)]), collapse = ""),
            string2 =  paste(unique(string2[!is.na(string2)]), collapse = ""))
```

Output:

```
id    session string1       string2       
  <fct> <fct>   <chr>         <chr>         
1 a     s1      first_string1 second_string2
2 b     s2      first_string3 second_string4
```